# the meaning of the logs files in Hadoop

Tags: logging, hadoop

I try to analyze the job characteristics of Hadoop system with different applications, e.g., MapReduce, Hbase etc. 
There are some log files for different purposes, e.g., namenode, datanode and jobtrack. The log file is in certain format. 
Is there anybody who knows the exact meaning of each item in the log file? Or where I can find the related docs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop uses [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) to handle the logs. Looks you have not modified the configuration. I don't know which version you are using. So assume you are using the configuration here: https://github.com/apache/hadoop-common/blob/ade66f948e2cf0d5bd46a212b58c8ca3c85aba39/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/conf/log4j.properties

The log format outputted to console is defined as

```
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
```

- %d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}: date and its format.
- %p: the priority of the logging event. Such as, INFO, DEBUG, ERROR.
- %c: the category of the logging event. In Hadoop, it's usually the class name.
- %m: the log message.
- %n: the platform dependent line separator character or characters.

More information can be found here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html

An output example is

```
14/05/19 06:50:42 INFO http.HttpServer: Jetty bound to port 42253
```

Comment: I think the OP was about the meaning of the logs and not how to change what was being logged.